# Flex items lining up in a row (inline) but should stack vertically

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to center the text in my `div` but that seems to make it so that the two lines of text, which are both `p` tags, aren't displaying with normal block properties (i.e. they are smooshing onto the same line instead of stacking, which is the desired result).

I am open to either removing flexbox, if I can get the text (the two `p` tags) within the `div` to align both vertically and horizontally or keeping flex and getting the `p` tags to each take up the full width of the `div`, like a block element.

The "my name is" part should be on top of the actual name:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class='nametag' id='bernie'>
    <p class='hello'>Hello, my name is</p>
    <p class='name'>Bernie</p>
</div>
<div class='nametag' id='carly'>
    <p class='hello'>Hello, my name is</p>
    <p class='name'>Carly</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nametag {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 6em;
    width: 10em;
    color: red;
    background-color: white;
    bottom: 30%;
    position: absolute;

    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    flex-flow: row-wrap;
}

.hello {
    font-size: .7em;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-wrap;
    width: 5em;
}

.name {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-wrap;
    width: 5em;
}
```

Comment: *p tags, aren't displaying with normal block properties* ... Once you create a flex container, the children become flex items in a *flex formatting context*. It doesn't matter if the children were previously inline or block elements, they are now flex items subject to flex (not block) layout rules. By default, a flex container aligns flex items in a row (like in your image). As mentioned in an answer, you can override the row default by specifying flex-direction: column, which stacks items vertically.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few small problems.

You are using the compound property `flex-flow`, which lets you specify both the `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap` values in one rule (the same way you can say `border: 1px solid black;`). Now, the value you have here is `row-wrap`, which is actually being ignored because it's not a valid value (it would be `row wrap` -- one value for direction, one for wrap mode).

But! You don't want `row` anyway. Row layout is default, which is why you're getting the first item to the left of the second. You want `column`. You can set this by either using `flex-direction: column` or `flex-flow: column wrap` (assuming you want wrapping to be possible).

Final note: you also set `flex-flow` and `display: flex` on the child elements. These rules both pertain to an element with flex *children*. If these elements are really just going to be `<p>` tags, you only need them on the `.nametag` ('flex parent') selector.

Comment: You're welcome. Might I recommend updating the title to something like "How to prevent CSS flex block elements from displaying inline" since that may help other people find the answer? (The "inline" bit is a bit misleading, but that is actually good to have in there since it's the natural assumption about what's happening and may help googlers).